# read binary file (.bin) as byte array in Pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a .bin file and want to partition it and get it as byte array. but using map() don't help me and when I get size of whole data, it isn't size of my file (it is bigger than file's size)

For test it, I was faced with other problem, when I use getNumPartitions()  to get number of partition, 1 is printed in output but function that use in map(), is called more than one. Another problem is when sum the size of each partition, result isn't my file's size and bigger than it(I get size with sys.getsizeof() in map() function)

1. How read .bin file as byte array? and,
2. What's a way for partition file as fixed size? and,
3. Can I make partition with overlapping and set location of spliting?

Comment: How did you load your `.bin` file?

Comment: @WoodChopper with textFile()

Answer (score 1):

For fixed size, take a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.binaryRecords

Comment: thanks alot, is it same as textFile()? can I replace it with textFile witout change in other code?what thing I must import? I use spark 1.4.4

Comment: @user3416282 a) I hope so, and b) no idea, I don't use python.